# Visual Studio 2015 Executable Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing an unattended installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition from a network share using the following guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx

I've done everything as directed (and have successfully done this before with VS 2015 Enterprise) however for some reason the install isn't completing properly. It seems as the the Visual Studio executable is missing after the installation has finished (this happens doing it both in attended and unattended mode). Has anyone else run in to this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

It seems I have found a devenv.exe in the Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ folder that launches the IDE. It seems that my unattended install didn't set up the icons for the IDE properly either in the start menu or on the desktop.

Comment: This may happen if SQL Server Data Tools or another product that uses the Visual Studio 2015 Shell is installed...